# ExtJS RESTful service fail to handle json data

Tags: javascript, json, rest, extjs5

I implement simple RESTful Service. These are Rest request url and the response json data.

http://localhost:8080/RESTfulTestWeb/rest/services/getJson/aupres

```
{"id":"aupres","passwd":"aaa","age":45,"name":"joseph"}
```

The problem is ExtJS Store object client can not handle the above json data. These are ExtJS client codes

```
Ext.define('extjs.model.Member', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields : [{
        name : 'id',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'passwd',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'age',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'name',
        type : 'string'
    }]  
});

Ext.onReady(function () {

    var members = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

        model : 'extjs.model.Member',
        //autoLoad : true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/RESTfulTestWeb/rest/services/getJson/aupres',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'id',
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json'
            },
            listeners: {
                exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                        title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                        msg: operation.getError(),
                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                    })
                }
            }

        },
        listeners: {
            load: function(members, operation, success) {
                if(success) {
                    alert('response : ' + members.model.length)
                } else {
                    alert('it failed')
                }
            }
        }
    })

    var onButtonClick = function() {
        members.load()
    }
```

The respose is shown like below

```
"response : 0"
```

It seems my ExtJS codes fail to contain the json data.

Comment: Did you test without `reader` and `writer` config? (Advise: you should allways configure the proxy in the model, because the proxy and the model are bound)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI You can overwrite toString() method of your class . then you can get exact.

Like you want data on ["id":"aupres","passwd":"aaa","age":45,"name":"joseph"}]
or some other format

Comment: I am afraid I am newbie in javascript so I have no idea how to overwrite toString method, Kindly inform me the sample code or refer. site. Thanks

Comment: toString() you have to overwride from server side . in java code you have to overwrite not in you client code

Answer (score 1):

The rest proxy reader in ExtJs 5 and up looks for a `rootProperty:` instead of `root:`.

Comment: You also don't want to use the rootProperty of 'id' - it's expecting to find an object there that it can turn into the model. Given the JSON shown above, you don't want a rootProperty at all.